# Summation without using for loops - python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am looking to perform a summation that, for the sake of this question, can take the form:
[image]

NOTE: Apologies, I have changed the equation as the original was not getting the problem across in the way I intended.

Ideally I would like to solve f(t) without using a for loop, as there are lots of different values of n and t to pass in. For example, the worst case scenario would be two for loops, taking the form:

```
import numpy as np
import math 

for t in range(len(ft)):
    sum=0
    for n in range(1,len(N)):
        sum += np.sin(math.pow(n,2) * t)
    ft[t] = sum
```

I have improved this to only have one for loop, taking the form:

```
for t in range(len(ft)):
    n = np.arange(1,N)
    ft[t] = np.sum(np.sin(math.pow(n,2) * t))
```

Is there a way of further simplifying this to avoid having to iterate through all values of t? For my purposes, the summation that I need is too time expensive while having to loop through all values of t.

UPDATE: The actual equation I have trying to solve, since simplifying it for the sake of finding a solution appears to be causing confusion, is:

[image]

I can simplify it down to a single for loop through the range of t values (similar to the example shown). I am hoping to simplify it further as there are about 90000 t values to iterate through.

Comment: Could `np.vectorize` help? (should make the computation of f(t) parallel with numpy array)

Comment: Sum of n^2 is the same for every `t`. Can't you just calculate it once and then multiply `t` by this constant to get `ft`?

Comment: gereleth, yes you are right, but this is my mistake for choosing this particular example. I have not listed the actually f(t) I need to solve, because it is more complicated than the question requires. For arguments sake, lets say it is sin(tn^2), will change this now.

Comment: are you hoping to meomize partial results as `n**2 * t`-arguments may come up repeatedly (i.e. you have the same  `n**2 * t` for different values of `n` and `t`)? otherwise i see not much potential for optimization... and if that is your *exact* function you might even use identities related to `sin`.

Comment: it seems I have caused more confusion that planned in simplifying the problem, that is my mistake. The actual equation I am looking to solve is now included

Comment: Is t constrained to be an integer?

Comment: in this case, yes

Answer (score 0):

Sine is a periodic function. You can exploit this to perform a smaller number of sums than N sums as values will repeat - if not exactly due to number spacings, you can find the relative phaseshift to change the summed values for each new period within N terms.

Comment: definitely, though unfortunately, the problem I am looking to solve does not have the same periodicity (I simplified the problem to try and highlight what I wanted to do, but I appear to have inadvertently led the answers offtrack). The solution I am after is a cross correlation of two waveforms based on their instantaneous phase, so I don't expect a simple periodic solution.

Comment: But your combined waveform is periodic. See http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cosx+-+sinx&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 0):

You can perform Einstein summation in numpy to avoid for loops

```
np.sin(np.einsum('i,ji',np.arange(1,N)**2,np.tile(np.arange(len(ft))[:,None],N-1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't get the question, but isn't it as simple as:

```
mysum(t, N):
    return sum(map(lambda n : sin(t*n*n), range(N)))
```

Comment: I am not very familiar lambda operation and map function, will check these out, but this doesn't seem like it would solve the problem of not having to still iterate through the different values of t, calling mysum()? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Well, you have multiple items to go through, so *whatever operation you decide to use will have to iterate through your items* (unless you find an equivalent direct mathematical expression). What `map` is doing here is performing the iteration for you, so that you don't have to think about it. The iteration has been "abstracted away", but will nevertheless be performed by the python interpreter.

Comment: yeah, I guess I am looking for a direct mathematical expression, in the same way that you can use matrix multiplication instead of using iterating through all values to solve a summation problem.

Comment: the computer will still iterate through your matrix, though.